# Jenkins - Passing parameter to other job without triggering it for freestyle project

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to pass a parameter to another job. But after selecting "Trigger parameterized build on other projects". It auto triggering that downstream job. But I need that job to be triggered by me and the only parameter needs to be pass.

Can someone help me here, please?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are passing predefined parameters in your upstream project.

*Under Post build actions :- Add Parameter > Predefined Parameters in reference to your downstream project.*

Now Building your upstream project will automatically trigger your downstream project, with the parameter you are passing from the upstream project.

Step by step [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqVHdiWAyYQ)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, Automatic trigger and parameter passing are working for me from upstream to downstream projects. But I want to pass the only parameter, But the trigger should be done by me. That is not happening.

Comment: Probably you are asking for "Build Triggers Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built" option. Please refer to the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803165/does-jenkins-create-upstream-downstream-automatically)